# Date picker : disable date in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Now am working with j Query date picker.How to disable date before a particular date using j Query?

```
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
  min:new Date(2013, 12, 12)
});
```

Comment: You can use `minDate`

Comment: This question does not demonstrate *any* research effort.

Comment: use the [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `minDate`

```
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
    minDate: YourDateObject
});
```

SEE [Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
```

For detail, visit the following link. [Jquery UI Datepicker: Date range](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this syntax:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "altField", "#actualDate" );
```

Here is example:

```
$( "#YourElementID" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", yourDateVariable );
```

Where yourDateVariable contains any date in it.